# R - Using the Naive Bayes classifier for combination of categorical and text data

Tags: r, naivebayes

My input dataset named "Classify" contains text columns as well as categorical columns. This dataset is already classified. Sample shown below:

[image: Click here to view sample]

I have classified the data(the "Room classification" column) based upon reading the text columns as well as the categorical columns. I have used the columns **Description(text column), AirConditioning(Categorical column), Lighting(Categorical column), Door type (Categorical column)** in order to derive at the classification column(Room classification). Now, I have another prediction dataset on which I have to make the prediction of "Room classification" based on the rules used for classifying the  Classified data which is shown in the above image.

I want to use the Naive Bayes algorithm for this classification.
I tried the following version of naive Bayes:

**Creating a classifier model:** (I omitted the Description column below because only categorical columns can be given as input)

```
classifier <- naiveBayes(Room.classification~ AirConditioning + Lighting + Door.type , data = Classify)
```

Now i use the above classifier model to predict the new dataset. **I am not able to use the Description column as input to the model along with the categorical columns but I badly want to use it.**

I tried another version known as multinomial naive bayes which considers only the text column, creates a model based on DTM of the text column and in turn predicts the new set. I have followed the exact steps in the below link for doing so. But this version only considers the text column i.e Description. I am not able to club the categorical columns along with the text column for creating the model.

https://rpubs.com/cen0te/naivebayes-sentimentpolarity

I want to use a version of naive bayes such that the text column and the categorical columns are considered for creating a model. For the text column, the bag of words approach should be used by creating a DTM.

Please give me suggestions for doing so.

Comment: This is more a statistical question than anything else, and hence is better asked on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JorisMeys - This is specific to R since I want to know how this can be implemented in R.

Comment: On stats.stackexchange there are a lot of R experts that can explain you. The problem is not a coding problem but a problem of how to implement a certain method. This goes beyond the scope of stackoverflow. I'd also make your question a bit more clear. I'm a statistician and I frankly can't figure out exactly what you're trying to do. "Using a text variable" in a naive bayes algorithm doesn't make any sense without further explanation as to what it should do with the text. The article you link to converts this first to a numeric matrix...